# Unable to figure out ruby method "directory" and what it does

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am very new to ruby and was trying to understand some code when I got stuck at this snippet:

```
directory "test_dir" do
    action :create
    recursive true
end
```

I tried googling `directory` class but was unsuccessful. I found a class `Dir` but its not the same. I see that intuitively this snippet should create a new directory and name it `test_dir` but I do not want to assume things and move forward.

**EDIT**
This was a part of a chef-recipe which is used to launch a particular task. For the purposes of launching, it needs to create a directory and download some jars to it. There is an `execute` method below which goes like this:

```
execute 'deploy' do
    action :nothing
    # ignore exit status of storm kill command
    command <<-EOH
      set -e
      storm kill #{name} -w 1 || true
      sleep 3
      storm jar #{points to the jar}
    EOH
end
```

Sorry I have to be a bit obfuscated as some of the things are not open sourced.

Comment: `directory` is a method, not a class. Perhaps you could provide more context.

Comment: This looks like it's part of some DSL. What's the context around this block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [Directory](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Directory) resource of the [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) framework. (DSL stands for domain-specific language. Ruby is well suited for them.)

Answer (score 1):

It's the Chef internal DSL for Directory management. Read more here: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Directory

PS: The `recursive true` tells it to create the folder much like `mkdir -p`.

Answer (score 1):

`directory` is not a class, it is a method. I do not know what module it is a part of, but that snippet is about equivalent to this:

```
Kernel.directory.call("test_dir",lambda {action :create; recursive true})
```

That snippet uses some gem that adds a `directory` method to the Kernel object.

As others have mentioned, it is part of the directory management DSL [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/). A DSL is a set of methods integrated into the Kernel object; because of the very flexible method calling syntax of Ruby, method calls can look a lot like language keywords. That makes task specific commands (Domain Specific Languages: DSL) look very nice in Ruby; easy to use and flexible. Thus gems that add DSLs are very common.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you pasted is not really enough information to go on (need context; where is the snippet from?)

That said `directory` looks more like a method than a class.  First, it's lowercased and  classes are CamelCased.

If it's a method, it's defined somewhere within the application.  Have you tried something like this:

`grep -r "def directory" ./` or

`grep -r "directory" ./| grep "def"`

If not in the application itself, it would be defined in one of the application's dependencies (`grep -r "..." $GEM_HOME/gems` instead)